# Android nested tab navigation 4.2

Tags: android, tabs

I am using an ActionBar for my main page navigation which contains four tabs to the different areas in my app.

One of the areas is a maps section, which should contain two sub tabs to show a list of items populated from a SQLite database.

So basically, I would like to implement nested navigation from my page fragments. The code I have so far is:

```
   //MainActivity.java

            ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.rowlayout);

    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)         this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    RelativeLayout layoutView = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.action_bar_tab,   null);
    TextView tabText = (TextView) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.tabText);
    ImageView tabImage = (ImageView) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.tabImage);


    String dayOneName = getResources().getString(R.string.day_one);
    Tab tab = actionBar.newTab();
    tab.setIcon(R.drawable.cal);
    TabListener<AgendaMain> dayOne = new TabListener<AgendaMain>(this,
            dayOneName, AgendaMain.class);
    tab.setTabListener(dayOne); 
    // set custom view
    tabText.setText(dayOneName);
    tabImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.cal);
    tab.setCustomView(layoutView);
    actionBar.addTab(tab);

    // Plus three more navigation tabs


  private class TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {

    private Fragment mFragment;
    private final Activity mActivity;
    private final String mTag;
    private final Class<T> mClass;

    public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mTag = tag;
        mClass = clz;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // Check if the fragment is already initialized
        if (mFragment == null) {
            // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
            mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
        } else {
            // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
            ft.attach(mFragment);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if (mFragment != null) {
            // Detach the fragment, because another one is being attached
            ft.detach(mFragment);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // User selected the already selected tab. Usually do nothing.
    }
}
```

And the tabs above link to fragments, in which I want to add two new tabs, with both tabs showing a ListFragment.

I have tried implementing a FragmentTabHost from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html), but encounter problems between android.support.v4.app and the TabListener from MainActivity.java. All code is working so far, just trying to add tabs to fragments!

If anyone could suggest/show what the best method is to implement this it would be greatly appreciated (: I have only managed to show static content so far which is no good! (I shall post more of my code if requested, I doubt it would help as I have had no luck!)

Answer (score 0):

TabHost is a deprecated solution use a ViewPager instead, with a FragmentPagerAdapter or FragmentStatePagerAdapter implementation examples can be found here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html 
http://storkme.org/2011/12/tabs-done-right-viewpager-and-fragments/ 
http://droidapp.co.uk/2012/05/25/android-dev-actionbarsherlock-tabs-viewpager/

Comment: Use a ViewPager instead of what? I have an ActionBar and want to use nested tabs under one of the sections. e.g. Maps is in the action bar, and when the user clicks Maps, two more tabs will appear underneath. I just want normal tabs if possible, not a ViewPager :)

Comment: oh sorry... then I did not understand your question correctly... but what you want to do can't be done with standart techniques, then you need to implement a custom actionbar solution

Comment: Ahh ok, thanks for the help! :) I have only managed to create nested tabs with two rows of TabHost, but ideally wanted it with an ActionBar and tabs underneath, but can't find any examples :(